# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'key' (AppEngine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Currently i am working on a project in which i am trying to delete a row from my ndb entity. The code which i am using for deletion is

```
copyquery = joinrequest.query(joinrequest.email == "abc@test.com")
copyres = copyquery.get()
copyres.key.delete()
```

But it is not deleting it. It is giving this error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\WildPakistan\gigster\main.py", line 203, in dispatch
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\shaizi\PycharmProjects\WildPakistan\gigster\main.py", line 798, in get
    copyres.key.delete()
AttributeError: 'BlobKey' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

NDB Model Class Code

```
class joinrequest(ndb.Model):

name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
gender = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
d = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
m = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
y = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
phoneno = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
address = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
city = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
country = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
selfdescription = ndb.StringProperty(required=True) 

key = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
```

Comment: I have updated it but now i am getting this error.

Comment: Actually it is the whole code. I just want to delete a simple row from ndb model class. Do you want me to share the model class structure with you?

Comment: I am using the Blob Key for storing the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Models in the ndb package have a standard attribute named 'key'.

Your model is overwriting the key attribute with a `BlobKey` property.

This is why you get the exception

`AttributeError: 'BlobKey' object has no attribute 'delete'`

when calling `delete` on the instance's key.

Rename your `key` property to something else so that the call `key.delete()` will reach the standard key attribute.